# What exactly happens in a JAX-RS resource with an @Context SecurityContext field?

Tags: java, jax-rs

I wanted to implement some security into a JAX-RS web service. As a result I used Basic Authentication with TLS. Everything works fine, but now I wanna know what's behind that "magic".

- How can the `SecurityContext` interface act like a normal class?
- And what has the `@Context` have to do with it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no "magic" here, it's just [JAX-RS providers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13557442/what-does-provider-in-jax-rs-mean). The ones involved in this particular behavior are context providers.

When the JAX-RS implementation creates an instance of your resource it looks for fields or methods annotated with the `@Context` annotation. It then looks at the type of the annotated field and based on that delegates the instantiation to a provider. The provider then injects an appropriate implementation for that interface.

The [JAX-RS specification](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=311) describes the kind of things you can inject using the `@Context` annotation.