# Google App Engine Jersey error format json

Tags: java, google-app-engine, exception, jersey, jax-rs

I'm developing a REST API with Google App Engine JAVA with Jersey and JAX-RS.
I want to be able to send custom errors to users in JSON format, for that I'm using `javax.ws.rs.ext.ExceptionMapper`

All works well when I run the app with Jetty on my local machine, but when I deploy to Google I get the default HTML 404 page

Here is the resource code:

```
@GET
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
@Path("{id}")
public Customer getCustomer(@PathParam("id") String id) {
    Customer customer = getCustomer(id);
    if(customer == null)
        throw new NotFoundException("Customer not found");
    return customer;
}
```

The exception mapper:

```
@Provider
public class NotFoundExceptionMapper implements ExceptionMapper<NotFoundException> {

@Override
public Response toResponse(NotFoundException e) {
    ErrorMessage errorMessage = new ErrorMessage();
    errorMessage.setErrrorMessage(e.getMessage());
    errorMessage.setResponseCode(404);
    return Response.status(Response.Status.NOT_FOUND).entity(errorMessage).type(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_TYPE).build();
}    
}
```

I expect to get the JSON formatted ErrorMessage object as response, but all I get is the default HTML 404 page.

Comment: Can you specify/paste the server error stack?  whether your code throws NotFoundException?

Comment: Well Jersey catches the NotFoundException and maps it to HTTP 404 responce. So there is no stack

Comment: I hope this link will help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26903729/how-to-handle-service-unavailable-scenarios-with-jersey-rest

Comment: Not really, I am able to modify the HTML page I get when 404 occurs. But I want the response to be JSON formatted string

Comment: Can you log statements to confirm that the request is (a) actually invoking getCustomer(), and (b) invoking ExceptionMapper.toresponse()?

Comment: Try and set the property [`ServerProperties.RESPONSE_SET_STATUS_OVER_SEND_ERROR`](https://jersey.java.net/apidocs/2.22/jersey/org/glassfish/jersey/server/ServerProperties.html#RESPONSE_SET_STATUS_OVER_SEND_ERROR) to true

Comment: Yes, thank you! @peeskillet This was it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set the Jersey property [`ServerProperties.RESPONSE_SET_STATUS_OVER_SEND_ERROR`](https://eclipse-ee4j.github.io/jersey.github.io/apidocs/snapshot/jersey/org/glassfish/jersey/server/ServerProperties.html#RESPONSE_SET_STATUS_OVER_SEND_ERROR) to `true`.

> Whenever response status is 4xx or 5xx it is possible to choose between `sendError` or `setStatus` on container specific `Response` implementation. E.g. on servlet container Jersey can call `HttpServletResponse.setStatus(...)` or `HttpServletResponse.sendError(...)`.
>
> **Calling `sendError(...)` method usually resets entity, response headers and provide error page for specified status code** (e.g. servlet error-page configuration). However if you want to post-process response (e.g. by servlet filter) the only way to do it is calling `setStatus(...)` on container Response object.
>
> **If property value is true the method `Response.setStatus(...)` is used over default `Response.sendError(...)`**.
>
> Type of the property value is boolean. **The default value is false**.
>
> The name of the configuration property is `"jersey.config.server.response.setStatusOverSendError"`.